# Wget for Windows 10

Tags: windows, wget

I need Wget for my Laravel v5.2 & PhP v7 practice and I am stack since couple hours as I coudn't find any way to install Wget on Windows10 any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use pjp curl or file_get_contents

Comment: @Dagon I am a beginner and I completely don't know what does curl or file_get_contents mean :(

Comment: Since you have stated that you are a beginner, wget may not be the best tool for the job (as Dagon said). Have a look at [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) manual. Alternativelly, state what you are using wget for and maybe there is another option.

Comment: @Tigger I am using it to do some housekeeping and neat programming by removing CSS and JavaScript CDN links from my Html file and to put it in a separate file like: all.css and all.js, So I my app doesn't need to have so many http requests

Answer (score 0):

While this question is not strictly Laravel oriented, this question may get asked again.

There are a number of ways to install wget on Windows. The Chocolatey package manager has a build available for install:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/Wget

To install Chocolatey, follow their installation instructions:

https://chocolatey.org/install

There's also a number of other good tools for Windows Laravel dev available through Chocolatey, such as Redis (great for cache and queue work)

https://chocolatey.org/packages/redis

Take a look through the packages available to customise your Windows Laravel environment.